# "docker login" fails on Jenkins server with: Error response from daemon: ... unexpected end of JSON input: ""

Tags: image, azure, docker, jenkins, acr

We cannot do a docker login (or, equivalently, an "az acr login") to an existing azure image registry).  The "docker login" command (or the "az acr login") gets back:

Error response from daemon: Get https://xxxxx.azurecr.io/v2/: error parsing HTTP 400 response body: unexpected end of JSON input: ""

where xxxx is the name of an existing image registry.  The same command works fine when executed from a Unix bash shell on a desktop machine, so this seems to have something to do with the Jenkins environment.  The command fails the same way if we use acr credentials OR service-principal credentials.  Other postings about "unexpected end of HJON input" were resolved by determining that the image repository did not exist, but ours certainly does exist (because the same failing command works just fine from a plain Unix shell).

Comment: How do you run the docker login command in Jenkins? And how do you want to do? use the ACR image in Jenkins tasks?